# Syncing Ubuntu Devices

Tags: software-center, sync

I run several Ubuntu virtual machines.  I would like to keep them synced up, the installed software at least.

I found this article but it doesn't seem to pertain to 17.10 as the software center doesn't have a file menu, and doesn't offer a way to sign in or up for ubuntu software center account.  Is there a new way to do this or is it gone?

https://www.howtogeek.com/111989/how-to-sync-quickly-reinstall-applications-on-ubuntu/

Comment: That no longer exists. It was "Ubuntu-one". You could consider apt-clone

Comment: @Jean-Marie I do remember Ubuntu-one..  I signed up for it back in the day but never used it.  Anyway, why don't you move your comment to an answer, because `apt-clone` will work fine, in conjunction with `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your software synced you could use apt-clone. it will backup or restore your installed packages, software sources, signing keys and state.

```
sudo apt install apt-clone
man apt-clone
```